# Access to Wildfly <system-properties><property> through JNDI

Tags: jndi, wildfly, system-properties

is it possible to access Wildfly properties (defined in standalone.xml) through JNDI?
Like:

```
    <system-properties>
        <property name="MY_PROPERTY" value="some value"/>
...
    </system-properties>
```

and read it in java:

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:comp/env/MY_PROPERTY") 
private String property;
```

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to do that. Could you explain?

Comment: How about `System.getProperty("MY_PROPERTY")`?

Comment: Why don't you create your own properties file, bind it to the WildFly's system configuration file (*standalone.xml*) and `@Inject` your properties into your beans as needed?

Comment: In the same kind of idea as aribeiro's comment, check the use of Modules to hold configurations as described under https://stackoverflow.com/a/68771020/6585002

Answer (score 3):

`<system-properties>` are used to define environment variables and not JNDI variables. Define JNDI variables inside

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
<bindings>
...
<simple name="java:/env/MY_PROPERTY" value="some value"/>
</bindings>
</subsystem>
```

Now, you can read it as a JNDI.