# Setting per application properties on Wildfly

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-10

I am normally the Tomcat guy but we use Widlfly on one of our client project.

With Tomcat, I can set "per application" properties by creating a separate context for each application, just as [Tomcat documentation very nicely says](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context).

This way, my `WebApp1.war` can run with `my.property.value=Cat` and `WebApp2.war` can run with `my.property.value=Dog` at the same time.

I haven't found any similar documentation / feature with Wildfly. Could you please advice me how to set properties to applications individually, or point me to the documentation?

Thank you. :-)

Comment: What types of properties are you looking for? Like system properties?

Comment: Application properties. Like these: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html I would like to set for example "spring.datasource.url", with different values for different applications.

Comment: It looks like you'd just include an `application.properties` file in the deployment unless I'm missing something. It depends really on the application and how these properties are read where they can be set.

Comment: This will not work - I need to set them at the container level, not application level, since different deployments may have different values. Just as I linked with Tomcat. With Tomcat, I can create `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/MyApp1.xml` file where I set the properties like so: `<Context><Parameter name="prop1" value="value1"/></Context>`. I am looking for the same thing with Wildfly.

Comment: Looking at the Tomcat docs, "context parameters" may be the good keyword here...

Comment: I'm just not sure what could be done here. Using the `application.properties` or `web.xml` seems like the only way to me to keep the configuration in the deployment. A container configuration is global generally speaking.

Comment: OK, I will assume this is a Wildfly limitation for now and I will try to find a workaround for it. Tomcat allows per-context properties in a single container - I can have more config files for each application. Thank you for your help anyway - at least I know I must use a workaround.

Comment: Well I'm not sure I'd consider it a limitation of WildFly. It all depends on how your properties are read. System properties are global, so those can't be defined there. You could use a properties file in your deployment. You could use the web.xml. You could use JNDI. There are many options, but they all depend on how the properties are read by the application.

Comment: No, I don't need to care about how properties are read by my application - Spring handles this for me, the way I work with properties is for example via @Value("my.property") annotation on a class property. On Tomcat, you can set context parameters that are defined per context - on application deploy, these properties are visible to your application within a single container instance. This way, you can for example specify different Spring database connections for different apps on a single container using the same property. I linked all the docs that are related. The same works on WebSphere.

Comment: @PetrDvořák did you get any solution for this. i am getting same problem and have spend many hours but didn't get nay solution. if you have any alternate way or solution. please post as a answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AwanishKumar Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to do this "per context" configuration. On Wildfly, you can use JNDI where applicable (this way, you can set up more data sources), or use different property / ENV variable names for different application purpose, or multiple wildfly server instances (for example, if you use Docker infrastructure, this is not a big deal)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Wildfly, you can create modules holding properties:

- Under the *${JBOSS_HOME}/modules*, add a directory like *my/group/app1/conf/main*.
- Under the *${JBOSS_HOME}/modules/my/group/app1/conf/main*, create the file module.xml with content:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="my.group.app1.conf">
          <resources>
                  <resource-root path="." />
                  <!-- Insert resources here -->
          </resources>
  </module>
  ```
- Copy your **.properties* file(s) under the *${JBOSS_HOME}/modules/my/group/app1/conf/main*
- Add as dependency `<module name="my.group.app1.conf" export="true" />` in the  jboss-deployment-structure.xml of the WebApp1.war
- In a Spring XML, assuming you have in the configuration module a file named *my-app.properties* the properties can be loaded into the context with:

  ```
  <context:property-placeholder
          location="classpath*:*my-app.properties"
          local-override="false"
          ignore-unresolvable="false"/>
  ```

To have a configuration module for the WebApp2.war, just repeat the steps above but the new module must have its own unique name.

Comment: Thank you, modules seem to be the cleanest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I found a workaround for this problem. A asume, that `app1.war` and `app2.war` are different wars and not the same with different names.

Then you can use the Application initialization process at runtime to define per application a different `spring.config.name`. Instead of `application.properties` then every WAR (and of corse every jar) looks for a application specific called properties file.

```
/** Main Entry Point for this Application */
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "de.mach.selfservices")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

  // JAR init
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class);
    if (!System.getProperties().containsKey("spring.config.name")) {
      builder = builder.properties("spring.config.name:app1");
    }
    builder.run(args);
  }

  // WAR init
  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    if (!System.getProperties().containsKey("spring.config.name")) {
      builder = builder.properties("spring.config.name:app1");
    }    
    return builder.sources(Application.class);
  }
}
```

The second application has then `app2` in `spring.config.name`. In both cases the default behaviour of SpringBoot is like expected. It looks inside and outside the WAR/JAR for `app1.properties` or `app2.properties`. So you can put two files in `wildfly/standalone/configuration` and can configure both WARs independently.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following approach worked.
First i changed name of application properties.
Second i changed the path to configuration file using Wildfly configuration path.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

     @Override
     protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
       String configPath = System.getProperties().getProperty("jboss.server.config.dir") + "/";
       return builder
                    .properties("spring.config.name:my-app")
                    .properties("spring.config.location:" + configPath)
                    .sources(Application.class);
     }
     
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
     }
}
```